# Isn't this how to specify a passing information custom event?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flashdevelop

This game is a board game so it need to pass information but mostly not dynamically.

Is this the correct definition of a Custom Event?

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Set extends Event
    {
        public var addsub:Boolean;
        public var kanaex:String; 
        public var valueex:uint;
        public var xx:uint;
        public var yy:uint;

        public static const BOARD_SET_CHANGED:String = "BoardSetChanged";
        public static const BOX_SET_CHANGED:String = "BoxSetChanged";

        public function Set(type:String, addsub1:Boolean, kanaex1:String, valueex1:uint, xx1:uint,yy1:uint,   bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
            addsub = addsub1;
            kanaex = kanaex1;
            valueex= valueex1;
            xx = xx1;
            yy = yy1; 
        }

        override public function clone():Event
        {
            return new Set(type, addsub, kanaex,valueex,xx,yy, bubbles, cancelable );
        }

        override public function toString():String
        {
            return formatToString("BoardSetChanged","addsub","kanaex","valueex","xx","yy","bubbles", "cancelable");
        }
    }
}
```

If so why does this code leave the 
event attributes undefined?

import Set;
import flash.events.*;

```
   this.addEventListener(Set.BOARD_SET_CHANGED, Exclusion);
private function Exclusion(e:Event)
            {
                var a:Boolean = e.addsub;
                var b:uint = e.xx;
                var c:uint = e.yy;
                if (a == true)
                {exclusionx.push(b);
                exclusiony.push(c); 
                }
                else if (a == false)
                {exclusionx.pop();
                 exclusiony.pop(); 
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the parameter of Exclusion to Set

```
private function Exclusion(e:Set):void {




}
```